# I am having problems with "error ';' expected"

Tags: java

Im having problem with this code. The console shows this error to me and I cannot figure it out. "file.java on line 7: error: ';' expected"

```
int adjacentElementsProduct(int[] inputArray) {
    int numberofElements = inputArray.length(); 
    int [] products = new int [numberofElements];
    for (int firstNumber = 0; numberofElements > firstNumber; firstNumber++) {
         products [firstNumber] = product (inputArray [firstNumber], inputArray [1+firstNumber]);
    };
    int maxValue () {
        int x = products [0];
        for (int i = 1; i < products.length; i++) {
            if (products [i] > x){
                x = products [i];
            }
        }
        return x;
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

If anyone could help me with this, I would really appreciate.
Thank you.

Comment: There are many problems here. Array don't have `length()` method, but `length` field. You are declaring method inside other method (you can't do that in Java). In `adjacentElementsProduct` method you are returning `maxValue` variable which is undefined, if you want to return result of `maxValue` method you need to write it as `return maxValue();` (most methods are meant to handle some arguments, if there are no arguments at least show that via `()`). Inside `maxValue` you are trying to access `products [0]` but there is no `products` array defined anywhere. There is also no `product` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `maxValue` is defined inside `adjacentElementsProduct`.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the method `maxValue` inside your `adjacentElementsProduct` method, to change this you will need to extract it and make it accept an array and return the int with the max value.

```
int maxValue (int[] products) {
    int x = products [0];
    for (int i = 1; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products [i] > x){
            x = products [i];
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

The method does not verify the length of the input array so you will need to take this into account

finally use it as `return maxValue(products);`

Answer (score 0):

Code is not properly formated because you have a method `maxValue` inside of method `adjacentElementsProduct`.

This is how it should be:

```
int adjacentElementsProduct(int[] inputArray) {
    int numberofElements = inputArray.length(); 
    int [] products = new int [numberofElements];
    for (int firstNumber = 0; numberofElements > firstNumber; firstNumber++) {
         products [firstNumber] = product (inputArray [firstNumber], inputArray [1+firstNumber]);
    }
    return maxValue;
}

int maxValue () {
    int x = products [0];
    for (int i = 1; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products [i] > x){
            x = products [i];
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Also, you have one one extra/useless semicolon after closing for loop, before declaration of maxValue method

Hope it helped

Comment: I am a beginner so I just realize that I can't put a method inside a method. Your comment helps me a lot. Thank you. :D .

Comment: @Thang Nguyen also, there are several problems with your code. Product is an array declared in adjacentElementsProduct method, method maxValue doesn't have access to it so it has to accept it as argument. Moreover, length is a property of an array, not a method so it should just be called inputArray.length;
In the end, your call of maxValue function is also not okay, it should be called as return maxValue();  (of course, if you really want to call it in return statement)

Answer (score 0):

To put everyone's comments into words.  Arrays use a data field to access length, because it is not a method you don't use ().

```
array.length
```

Next thing is your for loop has a semicolon at the end of the last bracket which prevents it from even happening.  So take that out.

Next you can't declare a method inside of another method.  Write the second method outside this method and then call it inside the other one.

Next you cant call the method nextValue like you did.  Even though you can't put it there to call it you have to call it like so:

What you did:

```
return maxValue;
```

What you should do:

```
/*something*/.nextValue();
```

Fix these things and you should get rid of the errors.